# ViewPager + FragmentStatePageAdapter : what does this warning "not updated inline" mean?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

My app consists of a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentStatePageAdapter`. Since I have updated to Lollipop / AppCompat I am getting these warnings everytime I swipe the page (on my previous test devices based on KitKat/Holo I didn't get any warning)

```
W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for FunqSlide[subscriptions/#768L3/PLAY] not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for FunqSlide[trending/#2560L2/PLAY] not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for FunqSlide[timeline/#512L3/PLAY] not updated inline; expected state 3
```

As you see, all the warnings come in sequence after every swipe (One for every instantiated fragment, as I have the `ViewPager` configured to keep 3 offscreen fragments alive)

However, the app works OK, I don't detect any failure or mis-update, as related questions here talk about.

Can anybody tell me what this warning means, and if should worry
about it? I don't even know what "state" the `FragmentManager` is talking about :(

Comment: I hope this link will help you to find a solution- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783098/android-viewpager-loading-incorrect-fragments

Comment: thanks! I already saw that question, unfortunately they don't explain what the warning is about, and the question is focused on solving a specific problem (that I don't have)