# Options menu showing at different fragments(mostly in neighbour Fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu, fragmentmanager

My view pager's Adapter is like:

```
    public Pager(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
        super(fm);
        this.tabCount = tabCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new frag1();
            case 1:
                return new frag2();
            case 2:
                return new frag1();
            case 3:
                return new frag2();
            case 4:
                return new frag1();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

how i set the tablayout and viewpager in java class:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        }

    Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.beginFakeDrag();
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

I am getting weird error look like this:

```
 W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for frag2{2428405 #1 id=0x7f0c006a} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
```

so how can i fix this issue?
I am getting answers from stack but it doesn't solve my issue,
so anyone have any knowledge about this, kindly help me!

Comment: Try this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783098/android-viewpager-loading-incorrect-fragments

Comment: i tried this also but didn't work for me! @Manish

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));` with `tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Firstly i used this method, then from stack i change the addOnPageChangeListener. :) @Manish

Comment: Ok..i will share my code. I am doing exactly same. As your xml will contains TabLayout with ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the `tabLayout` with the `viewPager` with `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)` instead of adding the tabs manually in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

available_bus_fragment.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:background="#d4d4d4"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e8e8e8"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java is adapter for ViewPager.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {


public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}


@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return  String.valueOf(position);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Fragment tab1 = new YourFragment1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            Fragment tab2 = new YourFragment1();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            Fragment tab3 = new YourFragment1();
            return tab3;
    }
    return null;
}}
```

This is your class where you set adapter of Viewpager.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
View rootView;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.tabclock,
        R.drawable.clock,
        R.drawable.tab_rupee
};

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.available_bus_fragment, null);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);
    setupTabIcons();

    return rootView;
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]).setTag("Departure").setText("Departure");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]).setTag("Duration").setText("Duration");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]).setTag("Price").setText("Price");
} }
```